# ImageViews taking a lot space than its need (XML)

Tags: android, xml, imageview, android-linearlayout

I want to show `ImageView` side-by-side in `HorizontalScrollView` like android markets. I'm having problem with the space taking by `ImageView` inside the `LinearLayout` , here what I'm getting: images separated by long **uncontrolled** spaces.

EDIT: The `ScrollView` works fine, just want to minimize the distance between images and show images side-by-side.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I want it to be like this:

[image]

Here the `xml` code for this row:

```
 <LinearLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TableRow
    android:id="@+id/tableRow2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
     android:background="#afafafaf" >

         <HorizontalScrollView 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
           android:layout_height="wrap_content">  

              <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/_linearLayout"  
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:gravity="center">  

                 <ImageView android:id="@+id/_image"   
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                   android:background="#000000"
                   android:src="@drawable/icon_2"
                                            />   
                  <ImageView android:id="@+id/_image"   
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content"   
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                  android:background="#000000"
                  android:src="@drawable/icon_2"
                                            />   

             </LinearLayout>  

       </HorizontalScrollView>  


  </TableRow>

 <TableRow> </TableRow> <!-- ........ other table rows for other things -->
```

Comment: I think your table row and scroll view width should be set to `fill_parent`. The way it is now, your scroll view might not expand to the width you want.

Comment: Sir, the scroll view expansion works fine, I want the spaces between images to be minimized

Answer (score 1):

Children of a `TableLayout` cant specify the `layout_width` attribute, it is ALWAYS `match_parent`, you can add a view to a `TableLayout` in which case that view will span the whole width. Also, unless the child is a`View` , `TableRow` 's height is ALWAYS `wrap_content`. So remove the `TableRow` element there everything should be fine. If you remove the `TableRow` element, be sure to NOT specify the `layout_width` of `HorizontalScrollView` to be `wrap_content`.
And also, `TableRow` is intended to be used a children inside of a `TableLayout` only, why would you nest `TableRow` inside a `LinearLayout` anyways.

Comment: Consider using `ViewPager` instead